# How to scrape location from list of websites

Tags: web-scraping

I have a list of URLs in a csv file and I would like to scrape locations for each website. I am really new in scraping, so I do not know what tool or language is better. Is there some method to make it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you vote down my question, can you give me the reason? I really have no idea of how to make it.

Answer (score 3):

Web scraping can be done in several ways. There are many tools online and it also depends on your selection of language that suits you. I worked on `Python` and can suggest you to try `Beautiful Soup`, `Requests` and other `API's`. You also need to understand `DOM` structure of the `webpage` you want to scrape. 
You may like to see documentation of `Beautiful Soup`: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Note that in a webpage, you need to understand DOM structure to search its location and extract location data accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I have done some researching on Beautiful Soup, but it seems Beautiful Soup can handle websites with similar format, so I can use find_all or the tag to retrieve information. However, the urls I get are from multiple sources, they have different styles. Can Beautiful Soup make it?

Comment: @SiruiLi You need to see pattern of the location data in different web page. I work on beautiful soup and can tell your question is very genuine. Yes, you need to code according to different format but if its in bulk, there must be some API associated with location data and if not, you need to code differently for different web pages.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will start from your hint!

Comment: @SiruiLi No problem, please tick mark this answer if this solved your problem/ gave idea how to work further. Thank you!